# Mount FTP site as virtual SD card

Tags: hard-drive, ftp, sd-card, virtual-disk

So basically what I'm trying to do is mount an FTP (which happens to be a SD card for my nintendo 3DS) as a virtual SD card on my windows computer, I've seen ways to mount the FTP as a normal virtual drive, but I haven't found any way to make the computer think that virtual drive is a SD card. Is there a way to do that?

I need to do this because a program I'm using (pkhex) detects the SD drive automatically so it can load a file from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt its possible as with an SD as mass storage it will have block level access while over FTP you dont really have file system access at all.

This would be better aimed at the software developer in question, and its helpful if you name the software in questions.

Comment: The software is called PKhex, (edited OP) and I know that some form of file system access is possible over FTPs because there are programs that do mount FTPs as drives, (WebDrive being the only specific example I can think of at the moment) but I haven't found anything that can make a virtual SD card drive for that. Correct me if I misunderstood what you are referring to.

Comment: @TorinKogut "there are programs that do mount FTPs as drives" does not imply that "some form of file system access is possible over FTPs". FTP is a *file* transfer protocol, and a drive can be abstracted as a set of files, but that doesn't give you *file system* access. (Oh, and please be careful to not confuse FTP and [FTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS), [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) or any of the number of others with similar acronyms...)

Comment: They PRETEND to mount it as a drive. Its fine if a program just needs to read off a file, but if it needs to block modify or lock the file this wont necessarily work. This is why theres a big difference between say SMB and SCSI mounts (have a google if you're interested). Theres some discussion of the same topic here: http://projectpokemon.org/forums/archive/index.php/t-44142-p-4.html

Comment: Well I'll mark you're answer as the answer since I think you're probably right about it being impossible, I think the way WebDrive works is it works more like dropbox then a normal FTP client, it downloads all the files on the FTP to the virtual drive it creates, you can then edit them as you would any other virtual drive and it will reupload the files afterwards, a similar system would work for my purposes I think but I havent been able to find anything that replicates a SD card, Oh well :/ thanks for your help :)